# wp_list_pages() remove one href element using jquery

Tags: wordpress

In a wordpress theme, I am using the wp_list_pages() function to generate the list of pages and its working great however I need help making one of the links redundant.

This is what wp_list_pages is outputting and the one that I need to change:

```
<li class="page_item page-item-12"><a href="http://mysite.com/page3">Page 3</a>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="http://mysite.com/page4">Page 4</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

I would like this to be

```
<li class="page_item page-item-12">Page 3 
 <ul>
  <li><a href="http://mysite.com/page4">Page 4</a></li>
 </ul>
</li>
```

This is the JQuery that I am using:

```
 <script>
 $(document).ready(function() {

 $(".page-item-12 a").removeAttr("href");
 });
 </script>
```

However, the Jquery is removing the links from all the < li > in the child ul as well which I do not want.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".page-item-12 > a").removeAttr("href");
     });
</script>
```

Comment: Leo, you have misunderstand my question I believe. I need to stop the link attribute been removed from a child <ul> of that <li>. The current code is currently taking out the href for the whole thing: <li>Link <ul><li>subpage</li></ul></li>

Comment: I have edited my code. Try it. Which will not remove link from the subpage link.

Answer (score 0):

if anyone needs a fix I found one:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".page-item-12 a").removeAttr("href");
});
</script>
```

However there is a new problem. If there are subpages, it also takes the link off them :( - How do I stop this?

Comment: I have edited my code. Try it. Which will not remove link from the subpage link.

Comment: Leo, Nope .page-item-12 a is the same as .page-item-12 > a. Tried it anyway and its still doing the wrong thing.

Comment: Could you please paste your code? for the entire li of .page-item-12